# Call/pass session created in lodinAction of adminController to changePassAction

Tags: php, mysql, session, zend-framework

How willI be able to pass session in login action to changepass action so that through session id password can be updated in mysql?

**Here is Login Action**

```
public function loginAction()
{
    session_start();
    $this->view->headTitle('Login');
    $request = $this->getRequest();

    $form    = new Application_Form_Login();
    $loginData = $request->getPost();

    if($loginData['Username'] != '' && $loginData['Password'] != ''){
         $comment = new Application_Model_Admin($request->getPost());
         $mapper  = new Application_Model_AdminMapper();
         $result = $mapper->findUserPass($comment->getUsername() , $comment->getPassword());

         foreach($result as $value){
            $res[] = $value['username'];
            $ids[] = $value['id'];
         }

         $_id = $result['0']['id'];
         if(count($result) > 0){
            $_SESSION['username'] = $res['0'];
            $_SESSION['id'] = $ids['0'];

            return $this->_helper->redirector('dashboard');

         }else{
            $message = "Please enter valid username & password !";
            $_SESSION['msg'] = $message;                
         }
    }else{
        $message = "Please enter valid username & password !";
        $_SESSION['msg'] = $message;
    }

   }
```

**dashboardAction**

```
public function dashboardAction()
{
$this->view->headTitle('Dashboard');

}
```

**changepassAction**

```
    public function changepassAction()
{
    $this->view->headTitle('Change Password');
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $data = $this->_request->getParams();
    $form    = new Application_Form_Changepass();

 if($this->getRequest()->isPost()){

         $comment = new Application_Model_Admin($request->getPost());
         $mapper  = new Application_Model_AdminMapper();
         $result = $mapper->save($comment);
         $this->view->count = $session->$_SESSION['id'];


        foreach($result as $value){
            $ids[] = $value['id'];
         }

            $_id = $result['0']['id'];
            if(count($result) > 0){
         $_POST['id'];
         $_SESSION['id'] = $ids['0'];
         }

      }

    $this->view->form = $form;
```